Getting a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
const Editor = ({ socketRef, roomId, onCodeChange }) => {
    const editorRef = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function init() {
            editorRef.current = Codemirror.fromTextArea(
                document.getElementById('realtimeEditor'),
                {
                    mode: { name: 'javascript', json: true },
                    theme: 'dracula',
                    autoCloseTags: true,
                    autoCloseBrackets: true,
                    lineNumbers: true,
                }
            );

            editorRef.current.on('change', (instance, changes) => {
                const { origin } = changes;
                const code = instance.getValue();
                onCodeChange(code);
                if (origin !== 'setValue') {
                    socketRef.current.emit(ACTIONS.CODE_CHANGE, {
                        roomId,
                        code,
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        init();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (socketRef.current) {
            socketRef.current.on(ACTIONS.CODE_CHANGE, ({ code }) => {
                if (code !== null) {
                    editorRef.current.setValue(code);
                }
            });
        }

        return () => {
            socketRef.current.off(ACTIONS.CODE_CHANGE);
        };
    }, [socketRef.current]);

    return <textarea id="realtimeEditor"></textarea>;
};

export default Editor;

I wanted to resolve this error but I have tried many things and I am not able to resolve this issue.
I have searched everywhere and even chatgpt cannot solve this issue. If anyone knows how to solve it then please let me know.
I've added all the libraries correctly and I don't know why this error is popping up.
